# Detect when a Module (DLL) is unloaded

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Is there a way to progammatically detect when a module - specifically a DLL - has been unloaded from a process?

I don't have the DLL source, so I can't change it's DLL entry point. Nor can I poll if the DLL is currently loaded because the DLL may be unloaded and then reloaded between polling.

**RESULTS**:

I ended up using jimharks solution of detouring the dll entry point and catching DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. I found detouring FreeLibrary() to work as well but code must be added to detect when the module is actually unloaded or if the reference count is just being decreased. Necrolis' link about finding the reference count was handy for on method of doing so.

I should note that I had problems with MSDetours not actually unloading the module from memory if a detour existed within it.

Comment: is this requirement for checking in code or while debugging?

Comment: @Chubsdad not precisely sure what you mean by "checking in code" but it's not for debugging.

Comment: Do you want to progammatically check if the module has been unloaded?

Comment: Yes, I should have made that clear. Edited to say such.

Comment: You can set a hook for calls to `FreeLibrary`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a less bad way then Necrolis's would be to use [Microsoft Research's Detours package](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to hook the dll's entry point to watch for DLL_PROCESS_DETACH notifications.

You can find the entry point given an HMODULE (as returned by LoadLibrary) using this function:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <DelayImp.h>


PVOID GetAddressOfEntryPoint(HMODULE hmod)
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pidh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hmod;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinth = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PBYTE)hmod + pidh->e_lfanew);
    PVOID pvEntry = (PBYTE)hmod + pinth->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

    return pvEntry;
}
```

Your entrypoint replacement could take direct action or increment a counter that you check for in your main loop or where it's important to you. (And should almost certainly call the original entrypoint.)

UPDATE: Thanks to @LeoDavidson for pointing this out in the comments below. Detours 4.0 is now licensed using the liberal MIT License.

I hope this helps.

Comment: One problem with Detours is you have to pay Microsoft $10,000 if you ever want to make a 64-bit build of your program. The free version lacks x64 support and the non-free version is ridiculously expensive. This has ruled out using Detours every time I've been tempted. :(

Comment: Good idea. I'll try this. On a side note: I had tried detouring FreeLibrary() to accomplish my goal. In the detour I'd call the FreeLibrary() trampoline and then use GetModuleHandle() to see if the module was still loaded. When I used my detour library, it worked. When I used MSDetours, it did not. I don't know why but when I use MSDetours to detour a DLL function, the DLL never seems to be unloaded unless the detour is detached.

Comment: @jay.lee In practice this solution has two problems, I don't know how do you deal with them. Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288601/detect-the-unloading-of-dlls

Comment: @LeoDavidson [Detours (4.x)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours) is now liberally licensed under MIT license. In the past I was also deterred by the licensing conditions for Detours. But this seems no longer to be a concern.

Comment: Use MinHook for x64, it's free and it's perfect.

Answer (score 10):

One very bad way(which was used by starcraft 2), is to make your program attach to itsself then monitor for the dll unload debug event(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679302(VS.85).aspx), else you'd either need to IAT hook `FreeLibrary` and `FreeLibraryEx` in the process or hotpatch the functions in kernel32 them monitor the names being passed and the global reference counts.

Comment: This is a fairly reasonable way.

Comment: I have some code that detours FreeLibrary() to do this but uses GetModuleHandle() to see if the module is still loaded. Is there something that can just check the reference count?

Comment: You'd need to spelunk through the PEB, luckly its all in the windows headers, this article should help: http://www.securityxploded.com/dllrefcount.php this way you can check if its the final unload before unloading it :)

Answer (score 9):

Try using [LdrRegisterDllNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347461.aspx) if you're on Vista or above. It does require using GetProcAddress to find the function address from ntdll.dll, but it's the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Don't fiddle with private functions, this is a bad idea.

Comment: It's no less "private" than whatever the OP is trying to do. Please explain your strange aversion to the Native API a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

@Necrolis, your link to “[The covert way to find the Reference Count of DLL](http://www.securityxploded.com/dllrefcount.php)” was just too intriguing for me to ignore because it contains the technical details I needed to implement this alternate solution (that I thought of yesterday, but was lacking the Windows Internals). Thanks. I voted for your answer because of the link you shared.

The linked article shows how to get to the internal `LDR_MODULE`:

```
struct _LDR_MODULE
     {
         LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
         LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
         LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
         PVOID BaseAddress;
         PVOID EntryPoint;
         ULONG SizeOfImage;
         UNICODE_STRING FullDllName;
         UNICODE_STRING BaseDllName;
         ULONG Flags;
         USHORT LoadCount;
         USHORT TlsIndex;
         LIST_ENTRY HashTableEntry;
         ULONG TimeDateStamp;
     } LDR_MODULE, *PLDR_MODULE;
```

Right here we have `EntryPoint`, Window's internal pointer to the module’s entry point. For a dll that’s `DllMain` (or the language run time function that eventually calls `DllMain`). What if we just change that? I wrote a test and it seems to work, at least on XP. The `DllMain` hook gets called with reason `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` just before the DLL unloads.

The `BaseAddress` is the same value as an `HMODULE` and is useful for finding the right `LDR_MODULE`. The `LoadCount` is here so we can track that. And finally `FullDllName` is helpful for debugging and makes it possible to search for DLL name instead of `HMODULE`.

This is all Windows internals. It’s (mostly) documented, but [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687420%28VS.85%29.aspx)  warns “ZwQueryInformationProcess may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows.”

Here’s a full example (but without full error checking). It seems to work but hasn’t seen much testing.

```
// HookDllEntryPoint.cpp by Jim Harkins (jimhark), Nov 2010

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winternl.h>

#include <process.h> // for _beginthread, only needed for testing


typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *pfnZwQueryInformationProcess)(
    __in       HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    __in       PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
    __out      PVOID ProcessInformation,
    __in       ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
    __out_opt  PULONG ReturnLength);

HMODULE hmodNtdll = LoadLibrary(_T("ntdll.dll"));

// Should test pZwQueryInformationProcess for NULL if you
// might ever run in an environment where this function
// is not available (like future version of Windows).

pfnZwQueryInformationProcess pZwQueryInformationProcess =
    (pfnZwQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(
        hmodNtdll,
        "ZwQueryInformationProcess");

typedef BOOL(WINAPI *PDLLMAIN) (
  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  __in  DWORD fdwReason,
  __in  LPVOID lpvReserved);


// Note: It's possible for pDllMainNew to be called before
// HookDllEntryPoint returns. If pDllMainNew calls the old
// function, it should pass a pointer to the variable used
// so we can set it here before we hook.

VOID HookDllEntryPoint(
    HMODULE hmod, PDLLMAIN pDllMainNew, PDLLMAIN *ppDllMainOld)
{
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi = {0};
    ULONG ulcbpbi = 0;

    NTSTATUS nts = (*pZwQueryInformationProcess)(
          GetCurrentProcess(),
          ProcessBasicInformation,
          &pbi,
          sizeof(pbi),
          &ulcbpbi);

    BOOL fFoundMod = FALSE;
    PLIST_ENTRY pcurModule =
        pbi.PebBaseAddress->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;

    while (!fFoundMod && pcurModule !=
        &pbi.PebBaseAddress->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList)
    {
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pldte = (PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)
              (CONTAINING_RECORD(
                  pcurModule, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks));

        // Note: pldte->FullDllName.Buffer is Unicode full DLL name
        //       *(PUSHORT)&pldte->Reserved5[1] is LoadCount

        if (pldte->DllBase == hmod)
        {
            fFoundMod = TRUE;
            *ppDllMainOld = (PDLLMAIN)pldte->Reserved3[0];
            pldte->Reserved3[0] = pDllMainNew;
        }

        pcurModule = pcurModule->Flink;
    }

    return;
}


PDLLMAIN pDllMain_advapi32 = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain_advapi32(
  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  __in  DWORD fdwReason,
  __in  LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    char *pszReason;

    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        pszReason = "DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH";
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        pszReason = "DLL_PROCESS_DETACH";
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        pszReason = "DLL_THREAD_ATTACH";
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        pszReason = "DLL_THREAD_DETACH";
        break;
    default:
        pszReason = "*UNKNOWN*";
        break;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("DllMain(0x%.8X, %s, 0x%.8X)\n",
        (int)hinstDLL, pszReason, (int)lpvReserved);
    printf("\n");

    if (NULL == pDllMain_advapi32)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return (*pDllMain_advapi32)(
            hinstDLL,
            fdwReason,
            lpvReserved);
    }
}

void TestThread(void *)
{
    // Do nothing
}

// Test HookDllEntryPoint
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HMODULE hmodAdvapi = LoadLibrary(L"advapi32.dll");
    printf("advapi32.dll Base Addr: 0x%.8X\n", (int)hmodAdvapi);

    HookDllEntryPoint(
        hmodAdvapi, DllMain_advapi32, &pDllMain_advapi32);

    _beginthread(TestThread, 0, NULL);
    Sleep(1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I am trying to detect the DLLs that are loaded/unloaded during debugging, does this approach still apply?