# Is it ok to wait in DllMain (PROCESS_DETATCH) as long as its not forever?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll

I am writing an interface Dll which communicates with hardware via USB. In order to full fill timing requirement for the hardware (keeping it from timing out with no operation messages etc.) I create a worker thread per lazy initialization as soon a as my "Open()" method is called. When my "close()" method is called I set a named "terminate" event which is monitored by the worker thread and wait for the worker to terminate. Termination takes up to a few hundred milliseconds because a few messages need to be exchanged with the hardware.

So far so good, the only problem is when a Program unloads the Dll without calling my "Close()" method... I solved this by setting the "terminate" event in DllMain (PROCESS_DETATCH) which I'm pretty sure I'm allowed to do and still full fill best practices. The only problem is if the Dll is unloaded without calling close but reloaded again before the old worker thread terminates I cause a timeout in the process that loads my Dll because I am waiting for the old worker thread to finish.

So here is my Question: will waiting on the worker thread terminating in DllMain (PROCESS_DETATCH) with a timeout of say 500 ms cause any problems if I only do it when a worker thread exists and only if I am being unloaded (via freeLibrary) and not when my whole process is being terminated, which I test by looking at the lpvReserved parameter?

Also: is there a better way of solving my problem generally?

Comment: I am not sure, if this is an answer to your question, but it is at least related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx

Comment: I hope you are not waiting for a thread exit? Because this cannot be done in the DllMain.

Comment: Can you make it a requirement that programs must call Close() before unloading your library?

Comment: @MarcSherman it really is a requirement, its just that I don't have control over the program that loads my DLL and it doesn't seem to care about my requirements

Comment: @Sergius yes, among other things, I am waiting for a thread to finish... whats the work around?

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR the ting about the "oldnewthing" is that if your using RAII the other resources besides RAM and handles may be being freed in the destructors. Named locks for example.

Comment: If it's a requirement, can you get your management to force it to be followed? Otherwise you're going to write all this special code that may introduce very subtle and hard to find bugs just because the program doesn't call Close(). While you wait in DllMain, your thread will own the loader lock and may cause deadlocks with other threads, even if they are not calling LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that will happen is make the thread which called `FreeLibrary` (FreeLibrary is not asychroneous, it waits for a return value) wait as long as your module is unloading.

I have made a few DLL's, sometimes even an loop like `while(!IsDebuggerAttached()){}` in DLLMain attach/detach and the programs which I tested behave just like they needed.

As for other problem solutions: Why would you need anything else besides DLLMain attach/detach  which has the same functionality?

Comment: I read somewhere that when DllMain (PROCESS_DETATCH) is called some global data may be corrupt or that some stuff may have been unloaded already. I am not that knowledgeable on this subject yet. Could this be a problem and when does it happen?

Comment: >Before unloading a library module, the system enables the module to detach from the process by calling the module's DllMain function, if it has one, with the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH value. Doing so gives the library module an opportunity to clean up resources allocated on behalf of the current process. After the entry-point function returns, the library module is removed from the address space of the current process.

Comment: that's from the winapi page, the only* unsafe way to call FreeLibrary is from DLLMain..
*in single threaded environments

Comment: but read this:|||
Use caution when calling FreeLibrary with a handle returned by GetModuleHandle. The GetModuleHandle function does not increment a module's reference count, so passing this handle to FreeLibrary can cause a module to be unloaded prematurely.|||
But this probbably doesn't affect you, or does it?

Comment: ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: if I call functions from another DLL in my cleanup routine how can windows guarantee that my PROCESS_DETACH was called before its PROCESS_DETACH in the case of program termination?

Comment: As for your previous comment there are many solution, the one that I would suggest is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242469/detect-when-a-module-dll-is-unloaded), but there is another hacky solution, which allows you to control which modules get unloaded, and when: [click](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2006/10/09/Preventing-a-DLL-from-being-unloaded-by-the-app-that-uses-it.aspx). if none of the above solutions is the one you're looking for I would personally  get the adress of a function in the DLL, and make a __try __catch statemend around to check if it exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a wait in my PROCESS_DETACH and it worked at first but in one corner case it ended up causing problems. The problem was that our debug output setup loaded a proprietary DLL to include version info in the debug output. If our DLL was loaded and unloaded quickly and there was enough going on in the background that this version info reading was slow to get going it could end up happening during the time that the process was waiting in PROCESS_DETACH which caused a deadlock.

For the future I have decided to never wait for anything in DllMin because anything I wait for could, in some corner case or after someone else adds functionality to some class which is touched, cause a deadlock on the loader lock.

I hope this advice helps someone in the future.