# C# - How can I get the unloaded modules list from a process?

Tags: c#, module

I need to get the process unloaded modules list as Process Hacker does.

[image: unloaded modules 1]

[image: unloaded modules 2]

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I honestly tried nothing because I'm searching for a way to do it but I found nothing in C#. I only found a way to get the unloaded modules list but in C++. So I'm asking here because I think my question would be useful for other users who are searching for a way to do it in C# like me.

Comment: Matteo, does Process Hacker know the unloaded modules if you open it after? If not, it probably saves a variable for each process of each module and then compare

Comment: I can't answer this for C#, but it's worth nothing that someone else was asking the [same question tagged c++/winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4242469/279251) - [`LdrRegisterDllNotification`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243520/279251) might be the way to go

Comment: @nalnpir Yes, it knows.